# bubble sort ideone time limit exceeded

Tags: c, sorting, bubble-sort

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {

    int a[5]={1,2,0,5,4},i,j,c;
    for(i=0;i<5;i++)    
    {
        for(j=0;j<5-i;j++){
            if(a[j]>a[j+1])
            {
                c=a[j];
                a[j]=a[j+1];
                a[j+1]=c;
            }
        }
    }
    for(i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
    printf("%d",a[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

ideone says "Time limit exceeded    time: 5 memory: 2048 signal:24"

but it works fine on  turbo compiler

Comment: Think about this: Once the inner loop has finished all elements at or before index `i` should be sorted. That means you inner loop should go from `i + 1` to the last element (`j < 5`), and you should swap element `i` and `j`.

Answer (score 6):

```
for(j=0;j<5-i;j++){
            if(a[j]>a[j+1])
```

`a[j+1]` is array out of bound access which will lead to undefined behavior

Answer (score 1):

Try this for bubble sort..Machine cycle will not be hampered in any compilers..

```
for (i = 0; i < count -1; i++)
      for (j = 0; j < ((count - 1) - i); j++) {
          if (memptr[j]>memptr[j+1]) {
              temp = memptr[j];
              memptr[j] = memptr[j + 1];
              memptr[j + 1] = temp;
          }
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int a[5]={1,2,0,5,4}
```

So, for the following index you will get the following content:

```
index   ->| 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
content ->| 1 | 2 | 0 | 5 | 4 |
```

Now In your outer loop `for(i=0;i<5;i++)`, for the first iteration `i = 0`, then the inner loop breaking condition will be,

```
for(j=0;j<5-i;j++)
```

or,

```
for(j=0;j<5-0;j++)
```

Hence the value of `j` will increase `0` to `4`.

Now think what will happen `a[j+1]`, when `j = 4`!

You are trying to access, `a[4+1]` or, `a[5]` where the `index` of array `a` is defined up to `4`.

So at `a[5]`, you will get [Undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Try:

```
for(j=0; j<5 -i -1; j++)
```