# Q: Relation between error time limit exceed and error SIGSEGV(exceeding bounds)

Tags: c, runtime-error, out-of-memory

In the given code I do not know why I get an error of time limit exceeded, previously I was getting an error of something like using elements outside bounds(SIGSEGV). 
after some edits, I am now getting time limit exceeded.
Do we have a relation between both types of errors?
I see this guy is also getting the same error, while the problem was of boundedness.
[bubble sort ideone time limit exceeded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30870312/bubble-sort-ideone-time-limit-exceeded)
as the name of both these errors suggests there shouldn't be any relations.
My code is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int mss(int n,int i,int pos,int arr[],int sum){
  int sum2=0;

  if(pos+i>n)return sum;

  for(int j=pos; j<pos+i; j++)
    sum2+=arr[j];

  sum+=sum2;

  pos=pos+i;
  i=i+1;

  return mss(n,i,pos,arr,sum);

}

int main(){
  int arr[100000],n,x=0,psum=0,k=1,px;
  scanf("%d",&n);
  for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
    scanf("%d",&arr[i]);
  }

  for(int z=0; z<n; z++){

  px=mss(n,k,z,arr,psum);

  if(px>x)
    x=px;

  }

  printf("%d",x);

  return 0;
}
```

P.S: the question I am solving is this:
https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/basic-programming/input-output/basics-of-input-output/practice-problems/algorithm/best-index-1-45a2f8ff/

Comment: There is no relation whatsoever between these two problems.

Comment: Programming challenges with automatic online judges use time limits to force you to use an efficient agorithm. You have implemented the task more or less literally, even with a not very efficient recursive approach. If you have a test case with 1e+5 array elements, this will take some seconds. One way to improve your algorithm is to store accumulated sums instead of array elements, so that `sum[i] = sum[i- 1] + a[i]` and `sum[0] = 0`. Summing all elemets in the interval `[a, b)` can then be done by just calculating `sum[b] - sum[a]`; you only need to determine the right bounds.